# ccny_rgbd package stop working when i launch hector_slam, does anyone know the reason

Tags: ros, ccny-rgbd, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am trying to run ccny_rgbd and hector_slam at the same time but when i start the hector_slam, the ccny_rgbd stops working. does anyone know why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199217/ccny_rgbd-package-stop-working-when-i-launch-hector_slam,-does-anyone-know-the-reason/) by [milorenus](https://answers.ros.org/users/21073/milorenus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some things to look out for:

- Make sure the node names are
  different. If you copied and pasted
  launch file code, it could be
  happening that both nodes are started
  with the same name, which could lead
  to the first getting killed as soon
  as the second one is started.
- Both
  approaches might publish localization
  information to tf. This could lead to
  various issues.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [milorenus](https://answers.ros.org/users/21073/milorenus/) on 2014-12-14**:
hi!
i tried to run only the hokuyo node without launching the hector_slam package and the same thing happened(ccny stopped working), do you think there is some kind of conflict between these two devices?